# How to fix problem with editing e.g. menu or list items

Tags: oracle-apex

I work on APEX 19.1, and i have a problem with editing e.g. lists. Problem concerns only items with "polish" characters..

For example i have list, which i use for menu. I have entry for example "Ą". When i create it and save it it save it as "A??". when I would like to edit via the form, error occurs

```
Session state protection violation: This may be caused by manual alteration of protected page item P4052_N. If you are unsure what caused this error, please contact the application administrator for assistance.
```

But i can edit it through "Grid Edit".

P4052_N it's an item used on administrating page 4052. This page is for editing List Entry.

[image]

I used inspect via Google Chrome and i found that it keeps the value with name of entry list. There is a problem only with entries that contains "polish" characters.

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error on APEX 19.1.0.00.15 running in Oracle's Free Tier. Look in the upper right-hand corner of the Application Builder for a "question mark" icon and click that, then select "About". What values do you have for REQUEST_CHARSET, NLS_CHARACTERSET, and DAD CHARACTERSET?

Comment: Dan thx for answer. REQUEST_CHARSET : AL32UTF8, NLS_CHARACTERSET : EE8MSWIN1250 and DAD CHARACTERSET:UTF-8. I think that the first doesn't match. Am i right?

Comment: The REQUEST_CHARSET, AL32UTF8, is good. It would be best if your database, NLS_CHARACTERSET, was using the same value. Are you using a translated version of APEX? What happens if you create your own form and try to save and then edit the data? Does that work fine? Is it just this one place where there's an issue?

Comment: I'm using default version of english APEX. It's only when i try to edit List Entry in application builder. When i create a hidden item and try to change this value from form on app (with "polish" char) there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by CAS filters.
I resolved it in this question:
[Encoding problem with APEX app builder caused by CAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830692/encoding-problem-with-apex-app-builder-caused-by-cas)